# Download artifact from Azure Devops Pipeline not as ZIP format

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am using the following:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{build_number}/artifacts?artifactName={artifact_name}&%24format=zip
```

To download the artifact from the pipeline.
Artifact is a single file - I want to get it as file format (exe), not inside a ZIP.

Can this be done?

Comment: Why can't you extract the archive after you download it?

Comment: it only returns `"application/zip", "application/json"` according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/get?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#response

Comment: So I don't think it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Yeah of course.

You can use **DownloadPipelineArtifact@2** Task .

For information check [DownloadPipelineArtifact@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)